# Regular expression to crop all text between two strings

Tags: regex

I have several output text files from an iterator that has values in which I am interested. The text file, is formatted such that extracting the values of interest is extremely time consuming. Up to now, I have just been deleting everything by hand to get a properly formatted text file, since all my regex attempts were unsuccessful. I am using **gedit**.

The values I am interested in are the epoch numbers and the val_loss numbers. Each epoch begins with 'Epoch #/150' and ends with 'val_loss: #' I am only interested in the # values, everything else needs to be deleted, so that I end up with a space delineated list of epoch_number loss_value like so:

```
4 0.0483
5 0.0356
6 0.0322
7 0.0289
...
150 9.431e-03
```

An example of the unformatted text output file looks like this:

```
Epoch 23/150
  4/500 [..............................] - ETA: 218s - loss: 0.0010
  8/500 [..............................] - ETA: 218s - loss: 9.6766e-04
 12/500 [..............................] - ETA: 216s - loss: 8.3595e-04
 16/500 [..............................] - ETA: 214s - loss: 7.7532e-04
 20/500 [>.............................] - ETA: 212s - loss: 7.4657e-04
 24/500 [>.............................] - ETA: 211s - loss: 8.4598e-04
 28/500 [>.............................] - ETA: 209s - loss: 8.4580e-04
 32/500 [>.............................] - ETA: 207s - loss: 8.7478e-04
 36/500 [=>............................] - ETA: 205s - loss: 8.5640e-04
 40/500 [=>............................] - ETA: 204s - loss: 8.4638e-04
 44/500 [=>............................] - ETA: 202s - loss: 8.6241e-04
 48/500 [=>............................] - ETA: 200s - loss: 8.4484e-04
 52/500 [==>...........................] - ETA: 198s - loss: 8.2193e-04
 56/500 [==>...........................] - ETA: 197s - loss: 7.9888e-04
 60/500 [==>...........................] - ETA: 195s - loss: 7.9895e-04
 64/500 [==>...........................] - ETA: 193s - loss: 7.9008e-04
 68/500 [===>..........................] - ETA: 191s - loss: 7.7757e-04
 72/500 [===>..........................] - ETA: 189s - loss: 7.6095e-04
 76/500 [===>..........................] - ETA: 188s - loss: 7.6289e-04
 80/500 [===>..........................] - ETA: 186s - loss: 7.7004e-04
 84/500 [====>.........................] - ETA: 184s - loss: 7.6538e-04
 88/500 [====>.........................] - ETA: 182s - loss: 7.6304e-04
 92/500 [====>.........................] - ETA: 181s - loss: 7.5736e-04
 96/500 [====>.........................] - ETA: 179s - loss: 7.5236e-04
100/500 [=====>........................] - ETA: 177s - loss: 7.4144e-04
104/500 [=====>........................] - ETA: 175s - loss: 7.4024e-04
108/500 [=====>........................] - ETA: 173s - loss: 7.2697e-04
112/500 [=====>........................] - ETA: 172s - loss: 7.2627e-04
116/500 [=====>........................] - ETA: 170s - loss: 7.2926e-04
120/500 [======>.......................] - ETA: 168s - loss: 7.2165e-04
124/500 [======>.......................] - ETA: 166s - loss: 7.2607e-04
128/500 [======>.......................] - ETA: 165s - loss: 7.3096e-04
132/500 [======>.......................] - ETA: 163s - loss: 7.4657e-04
136/500 [=======>......................] - ETA: 161s - loss: 7.4458e-04
140/500 [=======>......................] - ETA: 159s - loss: 7.3769e-04
144/500 [=======>......................] - ETA: 158s - loss: 7.3473e-04
148/500 [=======>......................] - ETA: 156s - loss: 7.4137e-04
152/500 [========>.....................] - ETA: 154s - loss: 7.4791e-04
156/500 [========>.....................] - ETA: 152s - loss: 7.4419e-04
160/500 [========>.....................] - ETA: 150s - loss: 7.3774e-04
164/500 [========>.....................] - ETA: 149s - loss: 7.4737e-04
168/500 [=========>....................] - ETA: 147s - loss: 7.4616e-04
172/500 [=========>....................] - ETA: 145s - loss: 7.4986e-04
176/500 [=========>....................] - ETA: 143s - loss: 7.5148e-04
180/500 [=========>....................] - ETA: 141s - loss: 7.4903e-04
184/500 [==========>...................] - ETA: 140s - loss: 7.5950e-04
188/500 [==========>...................] - ETA: 138s - loss: 7.5910e-04
192/500 [==========>...................] - ETA: 136s - loss: 7.6007e-04
196/500 [==========>...................] - ETA: 134s - loss: 7.5940e-04
200/500 [===========>..................] - ETA: 133s - loss: 7.5771e-04
204/500 [===========>..................] - ETA: 131s - loss: 7.5325e-04
208/500 [===========>..................] - ETA: 129s - loss: 7.5449e-04
212/500 [===========>..................] - ETA: 127s - loss: 7.5461e-04
216/500 [===========>..................] - ETA: 126s - loss: 7.5625e-04
220/500 [============>.................] - ETA: 124s - loss: 7.5089e-04
224/500 [============>.................] - ETA: 122s - loss: 7.5313e-04
228/500 [============>.................] - ETA: 120s - loss: 7.5623e-04
232/500 [============>.................] - ETA: 118s - loss: 7.5475e-04
236/500 [=============>................] - ETA: 117s - loss: 7.5316e-04
240/500 [=============>................] - ETA: 115s - loss: 7.5243e-04
244/500 [=============>................] - ETA: 113s - loss: 7.4972e-04
248/500 [=============>................] - ETA: 111s - loss: 7.4882e-04
252/500 [==============>...............] - ETA: 110s - loss: 7.4838e-04
256/500 [==============>...............] - ETA: 108s - loss: 7.4374e-04
260/500 [==============>...............] - ETA: 106s - loss: 7.4162e-04
264/500 [==============>...............] - ETA: 104s - loss: 7.6052e-04
268/500 [===============>..............] - ETA: 102s - loss: 7.5960e-04
272/500 [===============>..............] - ETA: 101s - loss: 7.5938e-04
276/500 [===============>..............] - ETA: 99s - loss: 7.5755e-04 
280/500 [===============>..............] - ETA: 97s - loss: 7.6338e-04
284/500 [================>.............] - ETA: 95s - loss: 7.6875e-04
288/500 [================>.............] - ETA: 94s - loss: 7.6677e-04
292/500 [================>.............] - ETA: 92s - loss: 7.6576e-04
296/500 [================>.............] - ETA: 90s - loss: 7.6407e-04
300/500 [=================>............] - ETA: 88s - loss: 7.6126e-04
304/500 [=================>............] - ETA: 86s - loss: 7.5781e-04
308/500 [=================>............] - ETA: 85s - loss: 7.5853e-04
312/500 [=================>............] - ETA: 83s - loss: 7.5757e-04
316/500 [=================>............] - ETA: 81s - loss: 7.5721e-04
320/500 [==================>...........] - ETA: 79s - loss: 7.6311e-04
324/500 [==================>...........] - ETA: 78s - loss: 7.5977e-04
328/500 [==================>...........] - ETA: 76s - loss: 7.5814e-04
332/500 [==================>...........] - ETA: 74s - loss: 7.5881e-04
336/500 [===================>..........] - ETA: 72s - loss: 7.5702e-04
340/500 [===================>..........] - ETA: 70s - loss: 7.5559e-04
344/500 [===================>..........] - ETA: 69s - loss: 7.5527e-04
348/500 [===================>..........] - ETA: 67s - loss: 7.5431e-04
352/500 [====================>.........] - ETA: 65s - loss: 7.5355e-04
356/500 [====================>.........] - ETA: 63s - loss: 7.5808e-04
360/500 [====================>.........] - ETA: 62s - loss: 7.5696e-04
364/500 [====================>.........] - ETA: 60s - loss: 7.5729e-04
368/500 [=====================>........] - ETA: 58s - loss: 7.5360e-04
372/500 [=====================>........] - ETA: 56s - loss: 7.6101e-04
376/500 [=====================>........] - ETA: 55s - loss: 7.6263e-04
380/500 [=====================>........] - ETA: 53s - loss: 7.6700e-04
384/500 [======================>.......] - ETA: 51s - loss: 7.7540e-04
388/500 [======================>.......] - ETA: 49s - loss: 7.8387e-04
392/500 [======================>.......] - ETA: 47s - loss: 7.8220e-04
396/500 [======================>.......] - ETA: 46s - loss: 7.8046e-04
400/500 [=======================>......] - ETA: 44s - loss: 7.8039e-04
404/500 [=======================>......] - ETA: 42s - loss: 7.8073e-04
408/500 [=======================>......] - ETA: 40s - loss: 7.8023e-04
412/500 [=======================>......] - ETA: 39s - loss: 7.8021e-04
416/500 [=======================>......] - ETA: 37s - loss: 7.8163e-04
420/500 [========================>.....] - ETA: 35s - loss: 7.7768e-04
424/500 [========================>.....] - ETA: 33s - loss: 7.7606e-04
428/500 [========================>.....] - ETA: 31s - loss: 7.7344e-04
432/500 [========================>.....] - ETA: 30s - loss: 7.7389e-04
436/500 [=========================>....] - ETA: 28s - loss: 7.7189e-04
440/500 [=========================>....] - ETA: 26s - loss: 7.7244e-04
444/500 [=========================>....] - ETA: 24s - loss: 7.7039e-04
448/500 [=========================>....] - ETA: 23s - loss: 7.6791e-04
452/500 [==========================>...] - ETA: 21s - loss: 7.6747e-04
456/500 [==========================>...] - ETA: 19s - loss: 7.6639e-04
460/500 [==========================>...] - ETA: 17s - loss: 7.6705e-04
464/500 [==========================>...] - ETA: 15s - loss: 7.6498e-04
468/500 [===========================>..] - ETA: 14s - loss: 7.6247e-04
472/500 [===========================>..] - ETA: 12s - loss: 7.6109e-04
476/500 [===========================>..] - ETA: 10s - loss: 7.6061e-04
480/500 [===========================>..] - ETA: 8s - loss: 7.5875e-04 
484/500 [============================>.] - ETA: 7s - loss: 7.5613e-04
488/500 [============================>.] - ETA: 5s - loss: 7.5422e-04
492/500 [============================>.] - ETA: 3s - loss: 7.5290e-04
496/500 [============================>.] - ETA: 1s - loss: 7.5591e-04
500/500 [==============================] - 231s - loss: 7.5847e-04 - val_loss: 0.0012
```

Just to clarify, there are, as you might guess from the numbers, 150 of these types of text blocks per file. I was planning on getting the file such that each line first looks like:

```
Epoch 23 val_loss: 0.0012
```

and then find all > delete the 'Epoch ' and 'val_loss: ' strings. Whatever was easier for the regex expression.

If any regex wizards know a solution for this file it would be much appreciated. Any solution, mixed or pure regex, is acceptable, so long as it is easier than manually deleting all unwanted information.

EDIT: For mac users wanting a regex editor that supports *. with match newline option, your only solution is likely to be notepad++ on mac through wine. Editors I tried include: macVim, gedit, komodo, atom, sublime, textwrangler, kate, and emacs.

You can easily install notepad++ through [wine bottler](http://winebottler.kronenberg.org/).

Comment: It's not clear what you need, could you post just **one** sample input line and **one** sample output line?

Comment: Would you consider a mix solution? Regex + bash or other language

You can easely get the Epoch number by using a regex to match the first number from first line and a second one to get the expression with `[val_loss: ]<float_number_regex>` from the last line.

Comment: Oh, sorry about that. So there are about 500 lines between the desired values of epoch and validation loss. So everything between
Epoch #/150...val_loss: #  (which are at the very beginning and end, respectively, of the blocks of text) is irrelevant and should be deleted. I am not sure what you mean by one sample input line and one sample output line.
A single output line should eventually look like
"epoch_number val_loss_number", for example '23 0.0012'

I would take ANY solution, mixed or pure regex, that is easier than manually deleting all unwanted information.

Comment: Did you try my answer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try that

```
Epoch\s(\d+)\/150(?:.*?)val_loss:\s+([0-9.]*)
```

Replace by:

```
\1 \2
```

Make sure to enable . matches new line

[Explanation here](https://regex101.com/r/2enekg/2)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I can see your expression works exactly as I need it to in the link you included, but it is unable to find a match in gedit, and none of the online regex sites will accept a text file as large as mine. I'm going to keep trying.

Comment: I tried in notepad++ too, it worked as expected. Only needed to check . mathces newline

Comment: You can try by removing some lines from the middle if the site won't let you paste so much text. Anyway there might be another issue like the one I had with regexr.com: it doesn't have the "single line" flag, which makes `.` match new lines as well. Make sure that's not the issue you are having. If it is, you can replace the dot with `[\s\S]`, making the middle parenthesis like this: `(?:[\s\S]*?)`. What programming language are you using?

Comment: I have tried this expression in gedit, emacs, MacVim, atom, Kate, and komodo and have not been able to find any matches. Unfortunately, I cannot use notepad++ on mac. Also, the [\s\S] solution Andrew suggested found some matches, but only the first 4, and it was not correctly formatted.

I am on mac osx, the file is a plain text file, outputted from python.

Comment: You can try this i atom (?:.|\n)*? instead of (?:.*?)

Comment: In atom, I got "No results found for Epoch\s(\d+)\/150(?:.|\n)*?val_loss:\s+([0-9.]*)"

I did get matches for (?:.|\r)*? however. It ended up replacing all lines with \1 \2 though. I think I'll have to wait until I am home on a windows machine to try out this expression.

Comment: I can't believe there won't be any text editor that supports *. in mac that matches newline option. It is a pretty common fetaure

Comment: Maverick, thanks for helping me with that expression! Got back home to my windows machine and it worked perfectly on notepad++! Thank you!